# Split a string by seperator, but providing a pointer to the string that should be split

Tags: go

I'm working on an ETL process that is transforming a custom log format into .csv. The whole thing is running inside lambda and thus heavily memory constrained.

I'm using `strings.Split(s, sep)`, which is working fine, but the string isn't passed as a pointer, which means every time a new copy is created and in the internal implementation of `strings.Split` other functions are called which all, in turn, are creating a new copy of the string.

Because of that, I'm looking for a way to split my log by "  " (double space) and only provide the string as a pointer.

Comment: Probably using byte slices and the `bytes` package would be more efficent in your case.

Comment: Copying a string value does not copy the bytes making up the actual string. String values are [small header structures](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader) (just two words in Go 1 through 1.15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/) package instead, because it uses byte slices instead which are not pointers itself.

From the [docs](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro):

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).

In my understanding casting a string to a byte does not cause copying the data.

Example with [bytes.Split](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Split):

```
sep := []byte("  ")
s := "my looooong string"

result := bytes.Split([]byte(s), sep)
for _, part := range result {
    fmt.Println(string(part))
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's a lot of work rewriting my libary to use []byte instead of string. I'll avoid premature optimization for now.